# My McClellan Oscillator graph getting too low at the end

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, stock, technical-indicator

I am making a stock McClellan-Oscillator indicator graph for DAX-30 stock index.
I have the following dataset where I have calculated the MO(McClellan Oscillator) from 'ADV'(advance) and 'RED'(reduce/decline).

[image]

The formula for MOC is :

```
e1 = ema19 of (advancing_issues - declining_issues)
e2 = ema39 of (advancing_issues - declining_issues)
mo = e1 - e2 (here 'mo' is the McClellan Oscillator)
```

I have used the following code to make the mo column:

```
difference = adv_dec_dax['ADV']-adv_dec_dax['RED']
ema19 = difference.ewm(span=19,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
ema39 = difference.ewm(span=39,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
adv_dec_dax['MO'] = ema19-ema39
```

I dont know what Have gone wrong , heres a comparative image of My graph and from other sources:

[image]

I have tried to be as precise as possible . I apologize for any mistakes. Any help will be appreciated. Thnx.